# AngularJS. $http.post does not work

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm new to programming. Anyway i'm trying to make a simple website that involves sending some numbers to a database. I'm using the AngularJS framework and so I'm using '$http.post()'. Here is my HTML and JS code:

```js
app.controller('RotaController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    
    $scope.options = [{time: '00:00', value: 0}, {time: '00:30', value: 0.5}, {time: '01:00', value: 1}, {time: '01:30', value: 1.5}]
  
    $scope.send = function() {
        $http.post('insert.php', {'name': $scope.time}) 
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            return alert('sent');
        });
        
        };
  }]);
```

```html
...usual HTML tags. inlcuding the AngularJS script!

<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> <select ng-model="time" ng-options="loop.value as loop.time for loop in options">  </select> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

..usual ending tags.
```

I then later use a button that executes the send() function upon clicking.
Now, the insert.php file definitely works as I've used it on a different project  and I've tested it on it's own. can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to determine what's going wrong here due to missing code. Are you getting any errors in your developer's console? (F12 -> console tab)

Comment: I solved the problem, there was no connection due to the location of the php document in my directories